# How to change the command prompt color in BASH?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal, konsole

I'd like to customize the color of just the command prompt of a BASH shell, while leaving the rest of the terminal using the default color scheme.

In example, I'm using one of the default color schemes that come with Konsole, "green on black", which, surprisingly enough, displays a green text over a black background.

Given the following example:

```
user@host:~> some command
output of some command
output of some command
output of some command
output of some command
output of some command
output of some command
output of some command
output of some command
user@host:~>
```

what should I do to make the terminal display only `user@host:~> some command` (or even just `user@host:~>` ) with a different color, let's say a light blue?

All of this in order to stand out more when the output occupies many lines, to make it more visible where the output starts and ends.

Answer (score 0):

Put this at the end of your ~/.bashrc

```
export PS1="\e[34m\u@\h:~> \e[36m"
```